# NextAuth role based login using credentials

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, user-roles, next-auth

I am trying to create a roled based login strategy using credentials. I was using [nextauth roled-base login tutorial](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/role-based-login-strategy)  but it was not working. 
`/api/auth/[...nextauth.ts]`

```
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
 providers: [
  Credentials({
   id: "credentials",
   name: "Credentials",
   credentials: {},
   async authorize(credentials) {
    const { email, password } = credentials as {
      email: string;
      password: string;
    };
    // perform login logic
    // find user from db
    if (email == "john@gmail.com" && password == "1234") {
      return {
        id: "1234",
        name: "John Doe",
        email: "john@gmail.com",
        role: "admin",
      };
    }
    throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
  },
}),
],
callbacks: {
jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
  console.log(token);
  if (user) {token.id = user.id};
  return token;
},
session: ({ session, token, user }) => {
  if (token) {
    session.id = token.id;
    session.user.role = user.role; //not working
  }
  return session;
},
},
session: {
strategy: "jwt",
},
pages: {
signIn: "/login",
// error: '/auth/error',
// signOut: 'auth/signout'
},
secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET,
};
```

I thought of creating a custom adapter using [nextauth adapter tutorial](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/models) but it seems I can only define extra field for user if I am using OAuth provider. I can't seem to find any of the same in the documentation for credentials provider. My other possible solution is to use custom jwt sign in method instead of using NextAuth, but I can't seem to find a good example online.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking if the user already exists?

```
if (session.user) {
    session.user.role = user.role
}
```

after login you can check if the **ROLE** field already appears in http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session

Answer (score 0):

https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/role-based-login-strategy/

they said that in callback of session should be props.user but in my case is not.

i fix it like this but i think it will slow down my code a lot ...

```html
  async session({ session, token }) {
      const user = await Users.findOne({ email: session.user.email });

      if (session.user) {
        session.user.role = user.role;
      }

      return session;
    },
```

Comment: Need link formatting

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `User` schema to save the user into a database, add a role property. For example, in `mongoose/mongodb`

```
role: {
    type: String,
    default: "user",
  },
```

default value is `user`, you can define different roles and maybe write an endpoint to update it. You do not need to make any change in `next-auth` config.

Now if you want to protect a route, write this `getServerSideProps`

```
export const getServerSideProps =async ({ req, params, store }) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    if (!session || session.user.role !== "admin") {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: "/login",
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error and this was my solution.
When you login, the user calls the jwt callback, then you can persist your user and user role in token, and then, to access the role from the session, and so you can call it without server side props, with useSession hook, you can persist the user from the token in the session. That way you will have access to the data of the user by calling the session or by calling the token

Do this in pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

```js
callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // Add role value to user object so it is passed along with session
      session.user.role = user?.role ? user.role : token.user.role
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      //if the user logs in, you save your user in token
      if (user){
        token.user=user
      }
      return Promise.resolve(token)
    },
  },
```