# Next-auth v4, how do I extend the information of the logged-in user?

Tags: authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

I tried the following, but I couldn't get the addition from the client and server side environment.

The callbacks function allows you to add to a session, but I just want to add user information and designate it as a default session.

// @types/next-auth.d.ts

```
import 'next-auth';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface User {
    id: string;
    name?: string | null;
    email?: string | null;
    image?: string | null;
    address?: string | null;
  }
}
```

// [...nextauth].ts

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { buildFeedbackPath, extractFeedback } from '../../../lib/user';
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        const filePath = buildFeedbackPath();
        const userData = extractFeedback(filePath);

        const user = userData.find((userinfo) => userinfo.email === credentials?.email);
        if (!user) {
          throw new Error('No user found!');
        }
        return { email: user.email, image: '11233', address: 'testr' };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // console.log('session!!', session.user);
      return session;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

serverside

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session = await unstable_getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions);

  console.log(session);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/login',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```

result

[image]

Why can't I expand the address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we add more properties in session callback:

```
 async session({ session, token, user }) {
    console.log('userin session', session);
    session.user.address = 'testr';
    return session;
},
```

[image]

Because if you visit `node_modules/next-auth/core/types.d.ts/Session` this is the `DefaultUser`

```
export interface DefaultUser {
    id: string;
    name?: string | null;
    email?: string | null;
    image?: string | null;
}
```

this is why, in your `console.log`, "name" property exists but its value does not exist, it returns `undefined`, but "image" exisits in `DefaultUser`, that is why you could `image: '11233'` but not "address" because "address" does not exist in `DefaultUser` properties.

Comment: If it can be added only in a session, should I communicate with the database once more if I want to have other data such as user rights?

Comment: you visit database to get the user info. you are already getting the user.  You could just return the user in authorize method. session object is state that server keeps to communicate with client in your case. You can modify it the way you want it.

Comment: For example, what should I do if I want to use the property name "role"? Is it possible to use only three things: email, name, and image?
If so, should I add the form session.user.role = 'admin' in callbacks?

Comment: you should be saving the role into the database anyways. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73658567/nextauth-role-based-login-using-credentials/74661194#74661194

Comment: @yahoo2344 I just realized that your approach should work too. can u create minimal code or github repo

Comment: ok bro wait!!!!

Comment: I just want to return user information by adding other attributes besides email, name, and image.
user {name:'', email:'', image:'', address:'' }

Comment: I think I figured out. will write an answer

Comment: I found a way. Friend!
After writing the code first, I accessed it from the session and it was printed normally!
Thanks for your help, buddy!


jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      user && (token.user = user);
      return token;
},

Answer (score 1):

In your `callbacks` you can set your token and session user:

```
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token && token.user) {
        session.user = token.user as User;
      }
      return session;
    },
  }
```